# Load, save high score on second view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to load and save my high score on only the gameOverViewController. I have successfully transferred the score from the secondViewController to the gameOverViewController. The gameOverViewController is like a normal game over screen that shows your score, high score and has retry and main menu button. I tried to set the highScoreLabel equal to the scoreGameOverLabel, it runs, but the highScore int stays at 0 and doesn't equal the gameOverScore.  I am trying to:

1. if score > high score , high score = score
2. if score < high score, high score remains same

   ```
   var addOne = 0
   class SecondViewController: UIViewController
   {

   @IBOutlet weak var score: UITextField!

   score.text = "\(addOne)"

   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   let gameOver = segue.destination as! GameOverViewController

   gameOver.gameOverText = score.text!
   gameOver.lastScore = addOne
   }
   ```

gameOverViewController

```
class GameOverViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func retryButton(_ sender: Any) {   
addOne = 0
  highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "%i", highScore) as String
} 

@IBAction func mainMenuButton(_ sender: Any) { 
addOne = 0
  highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "%i", highScore) as String
}        

var lastScore = 0
var highScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "high_score")  

@IBOutlet weak var highScoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var scoreGameOverLabel: UILabel!

var gameOver = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if lastScore > highScore {
        highScore = lastScore
       highScoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "%i", highScore) as String
        UserDefaults.standard.set(highScore, forKey: "high_score")
    }                 
    scoreGameOverLabel.text = gameOver       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SecondViewController`, try setting your last score.

```swift
gameOver.lastScore = addOne
```

In `GameOverViewController` add the `lastScore` variable and keep track of your high score.

```swift
var lastScore = 0
var highScore = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "high_score")

if lastScore > highScore {
    highScore = lastScore
    UserDefaults.standard.set(highScore, forKey: "high_score")
}
```

Comment: Storing it to `UserDefaults` will persist a users high score even when they leave your app. Can you show the error you're getting?

Comment: You were right, I had a typo. Now it is saving my score and highScore in the app, but when I close out of the app the highScore doesn't save.

Comment: Are you sure it's not saving?

Comment: Yes everytime I double tap home and close out of the app the highScore resets to 0.

Comment: If your updated code reflects the changes you made, you forgot to change highScore to be the same as my var where I load it...

Comment: In GameOverViewController replace your let highScore with what I originally wrote which will load it.

Comment: @ZDP did that help?

Comment: It saving now thank you, but when I double tap home and close out of the app it says the highScore is 0 until the previous highScore is broken. How could I get it to show the highScore all the time?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're missing some code in your question, but make sure you're setting your label text to the `highScore` variable which is retrieved from `UserDefaults`. Also delete `gameOver.gameOverText = score.text!` you don't need that anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**,

```
highScoreLabel = scoreGameOverLabel
```

**Should probably be**

```
 highScoreLabel.text = scoreGameOverLabel.text
```

Secondly, as per your snippet, in GameOverViewController there is no `addOne`, how are you setting it and using it to compare in If condition ?

Comment: The highScore int is still staying at 0.

Comment: You are not setting or incrementing the value of highScore anywhere after initialisation

Comment: I updated the code so addOne = highScore, but still not working and saying highScore is 0